# Blackberry Webworks interact with Java API

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I'm writing a BlackBerry app at the moment and find developing a nice UI quite challenging using the native Java SDK.

I've just been looking at WebWorks and it looks great for developing a UI but other than that it looks limited enough.

I'm wondering is it possible to develop my app UI in WebWorks and all other logic (Secure Storage, NFC access etc) using the Java JRE.

I would then be able to invoke the Java code from within WebWorks. Would there be much work involved in this?

I recently did this on iOS with a Javascript/HTML5 developer and it was a huge task. We pretty much had to develop the bride ourselved from scratch. If that's whats required i'll stick to doing everything in Java.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I guess, by using JavaScript extensions. check this link

https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/ww_developing/using_javascript_extensions_1866976_11.html

Comment: Thank you. I skimmed right past this because I was looking for "Java" not "Javascript"..